# Explanation of Brotli's encoder algorithm

Tags: compression, brotli

The Brotli compression format is excellently documented in [RFC 7932](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7932). You can just read this RFC top to bottom, and it tells you how the format works.

However, while you could probably implement a decoder (decompressor) based on the RFC alone, the RFC doesn't describe the **en**coder algorithm that is part of Google's reference C implementation (the `brotli` command line tool). In other words, it doesn't tell us what strategies the encoder uses at different quality levels to find an efficient compressed representation for a given input stream.

Of course I can always read the [encoder source](https://github.com/google/brotli/tree/master/c/enc), but I was wondering if there was an accessible high-level description of how the encoder works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I am aware of is a very brief description in [this article](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-brotli-new-compression.html):

> The higher data density is achieved by a 2nd order context modeling,
> re-use of entropy codes, larger memory window of past data and joint
> distribution codes.

More importantly, from the same article:

> the new algorithm is named after Swiss bakery products. Brötli means
> ‘small bread’ in Swiss German.

*Update:*

AardvarkSoup added a much better answer with [this comprehensive paper](https://madler.net/docs/brotli-description.pdf) on how Brotli works, by its authors.